# Check condition before segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have multiple segues set up but I want to stop it from going to the next view controller when a condition is met.
I have looked into the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier but i'm not sure how to implement it since I am working with multiple segues?
My current code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


if (([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"push_1"]) && ([self checkForNetwork] == YES))
{


    //Pass object to next viewcontroller
    ID * object = currentID
    //go to next viewcontroller
    [[segue destinationViewController] getID:object];
      }


if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"push2"] && ([self   checkForNetwork] == YES))
{


    //Pass object to next viewcontroller
    ID * object = currentID;
    //go to next viewcontroller
    [[segue destinationViewController] getID:object];

}

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"push3"] && ([self checkForNetwork] == YES))
{


    //Pass object to next viewcontroller
    ID * object = currentID;
    //go to next viewcontroller
    [[segue destinationViewController] getID:object];

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be what you want.

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if ( /*INSERT YOUR CONDITION HERE*/ ) {
         return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks John. I did not understand at first but it's perfectly clear now.